# API returns JSON formatted object

Tags: python, json, list, api, dictionary

I'm a week into teaching myself Python.  I'm trying to extract data from an API response that comes as a "UTF-8-encoded, JSON-formatted object".  The object appears to be a dict with 2 keys 'data' and 'results' which are of types 'list' and 'int' respectively. I know that the information I want to extract is in the 'data' list but I am at a loss as to how to access this list as it only has a len of 1 despite obviously having lots of data in the list.  I'm sure it is probably a newby error that many will face palm at, but I've spent many hours today trying and now have to admit defeat.  Any assistance would be great, thanks very much.

```
import requests
import json

#API key for the checkws
headers = {'X-API-Key': 'b441745a1b6a4aed8140b66154',}

#Get the weather data
r = requests.get('https://api.checkwx.com/metar/KJFK/decoded', headers=headers).json()

#print what type of data is in the object downloaded
print("The type of object in the response from the API is: ", type(r))

#print how many keys/items are in the object
print("There are ", len(r), "keys in this dict object")

#print what each key is called
print("The keys of the dict object are: ", r.keys())

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

#get the contents from each of the two keys
data = r.get('data')
results = r.get('results')

#print the type of each key
print("The 'data' key is of this type: ", type(data))
print("The 'results' key is of this type: ", type(results))

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

#print the contents of the list 'data'
print("The 'data' list has the following contents:")
print(data)

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

#print the length of the list 'data'
print("But the length of the list 'data' is ", len(data))
```

which results in the following return:

```
The type of object in the response from the API is:  <class 'dict'>
There are  2 keys in this dict object
The keys of the dict object are:  dict_keys(['data', 'results'])
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The 'data' key is of this type:  <class 'list'>
The 'results' key is of this type:  <class 'int'>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The 'data' list has the following contents:
[{'barometer': {'hg': 30.1, 'hpa': 1019.0, 'kpa': 101.93, 'mb': 1019.32}, 'ceiling': {'base_feet_agl': 7000, 'base_meters_agl': 2134, 'code': 'BKN', 'feet': 7000, 'meters': 2134, 'text': 'Broken'}, 'clouds': [{'base_feet_agl': 2800, 'base_meters_agl': 853, 'code': 'SCT', 'feet': 2800, 'meters': 853, 'text': 'Scattered'}, {'base_feet_agl': 7000, 'base_meters_agl': 2134, 'code': 'BKN', 'feet': 7000, 'meters': 2134, 'text': 'Broken'}, {'base_feet_agl': 22000, 'base_meters_agl': 6706, 'code': 'BKN', 'feet': 22000, 'meters': 6706, 'text': 'Broken'}], 'dewpoint': {'celsius': -1, 'fahrenheit': 30}, 'elevation': {'feet': 10, 'meters': 3}, 'flight_category': 'VFR', 'humidity': {'percent': 61}, 'icao': 'KJFK', 'observed': '2022-03-01T18:51Z', 'raw_text': 'KJFK 011851Z 18010KT 10SM SCT028 BKN070 BKN220 06/M01 A3010 RMK AO2 SLP191 T00611006', 'station': {'geometry': {'coordinates': [-73.7789, 40.639801], 'type': 'Point'}, 'location': 'New York, NY, USA', 'name': 'John F Kennedy International Airport', 'type': 'Airport'}, 'temperature': {'celsius': 6, 'fahrenheit': 43}, 'visibility': {'meters': '16,100', 'meters_float': 16100.0, 'miles': '10', 'miles_float': 10.0}, 'wind': {'degrees': 180, 'speed_kph': 19, 'speed_kts': 10, 'speed_mph': 12, 'speed_mps': 5}, 'windchill': {'celsius': 3, 'fahrenheit': 37}}]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
But the length of the list 'data' is  1
```

And print (r) gives the following:

```
{'data': [{'barometer': {'hg': 30.07, 'hpa': 1018.0, 'kpa': 101.83, 'mb': 1018.32}, 'ceiling': {'base_feet_agl': 10000, 'base_meters_agl': 3048, 'code': 'BKN', 'feet': 10000, 'meters': 3048, 'text': 'Broken'}, 'clouds': [{'base_feet_agl': 2600, 'base_meters_agl': 792, 'code': 'SCT', 'feet': 2600, 'meters': 792, 'text': 'Scattered'}, {'base_feet_agl': 10000, 'base_meters_agl': 3048, 'code': 'BKN', 'feet': 10000, 'meters': 3048, 'text': 'Broken'}, {'base_feet_agl': 25000, 'base_meters_agl': 7620, 'code': 'OVC', 'feet': 25000, 'meters': 7620, 'text': 'Overcast'}], 'dewpoint': {'celsius': 1, 'fahrenheit': 34}, 'elevation': {'feet': 10, 'meters': 3}, 'flight_category': 'VFR', 'humidity': {'percent': 66}, 'icao': 'KJFK', 'observed': '2022-03-01T19:51Z', 'raw_text': 'KJFK 011951Z 17012KT 10SM SCT026 BKN100 OVC250 07/01 A3007 RMK AO2 SLP182 T00670011', 'station': {'geometry': {'coordinates': [-73.7789, 40.639801], 'type': 'Point'}, 'location': 'New York, NY, USA', 'name': 'John F Kennedy International Airport', 'type': 'Airport'}, 'temperature': {'celsius': 7, 'fahrenheit': 45}, 'visibility': {'meters': '16,100', 'meters_float': 16100.0, 'miles': '10', 'miles_float': 10.0}, 'wind': {'degrees': 170, 'speed_kph': 22, 'speed_kts': 12, 'speed_mph': 14, 'speed_mps': 6}, 'windchill': {'celsius': 4, 'fahrenheit': 39}}], 'results': 1}
```

And print(data[0]) gives the following:

```
{'barometer': {'hg': 30.07, 'hpa': 1018.0, 'kpa': 101.83, 'mb': 1018.32}, 'ceiling': {'base_feet_agl': 10000, 'base_meters_agl': 3048, 'code': 'BKN', 'feet': 10000, 'meters': 3048, 'text': 'Broken'}, 'clouds': [{'base_feet_agl': 2600, 'base_meters_agl': 792, 'code': 'SCT', 'feet': 2600, 'meters': 792, 'text': 'Scattered'}, {'base_feet_agl': 10000, 'base_meters_agl': 3048, 'code': 'BKN', 'feet': 10000, 'meters': 3048, 'text': 'Broken'}, {'base_feet_agl': 25000, 'base_meters_agl': 7620, 'code': 'OVC', 'feet': 25000, 'meters': 7620, 'text': 'Overcast'}], 'dewpoint': {'celsius': 1, 'fahrenheit': 34}, 'elevation': {'feet': 10, 'meters': 3}, 'flight_category': 'VFR', 'humidity': {'percent': 66}, 'icao': 'KJFK', 'observed': '2022-03-01T19:51Z', 'raw_text': 'KJFK 011951Z 17012KT 10SM SCT026 BKN100 OVC250 07/01 A3007 RMK AO2 SLP182 T00670011', 'station': {'geometry': {'coordinates': [-73.7789, 40.639801], 'type': 'Point'}, 'location': 'New York, NY, USA', 'name': 'John F Kennedy International Airport', 'type': 'Airport'}, 'temperature': {'celsius': 7, 'fahrenheit': 45}, 'visibility': {'meters': '16,100', 'meters_float': 16100.0, 'miles': '10', 'miles_float': 10.0}, 'wind': {'degrees': 170, 'speed_kph': 22, 'speed_kts': 12, 'speed_mph': 14, 'speed_mps': 6}, 'windchill': {'celsius': 4, 'fahrenheit': 39}}
```

Comment: What does `print(r)` give you? That would make things so much clearer. In any case, if you have a complex object `a`, then `l = [a]` gives you a list containing just one object. In order to get at that object, use `l[0]`. Alternatively, ignore the fact that there's just one element and write a loop, even if it's only executed once for this particular case. BTW: For JSON, install JsonDiscovery in your browser and `jq` for the commandline. That data is only unreadable because it isn't formatted (pretty-printed), those tools do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll need to post the contents of print(r) in a separate answer as this comment doesn't have sufficient characters.

Comment: You should be able to [edit] your question to add info. It's not that important though, it was more of a hint how to inspect things.

Comment: Thanks, just added the print(r) response to the end of my question.  The print(data[0]) similar output as print(data) which I guess is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Look again. If `print(data)` gives you `[{...}]`, then `print(data[0])` should give you `{...}`.

Comment: Yes it does, but within the 'data[0]' list are other keys (barometer, ceiling, clouds etc) and also nested keys (hg, hpa, kpa, base_feet_agl etc) which I'd like to be able to parse each individually if possible.

Comment: Look at `type(data[0])`, it should be a `dict` and how to use that you already figured out.

Comment: Genius (you not me)  thanks so much, didn't realize a dict with a list embedded could then have an embedded dict in the list!  And that was my stumbling block that I just couldn't figure out, hopefully I can sort it from here.  Thanks again.